# More than 3 hours baking texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, texture-baking

I'm trying to bake the earth's interior procedural texture, but it says more than 3 hours remaining time.
I'm baking it to a 4k image.

Bake Type -> Diffuse

Contributions -> Only color

[image]

[image]

Does someone know why?

Comment: maybe the sampling is very high?

Comment: thank you... yeah I decreased the samples to 20 and now it bakes it in a few seconds but I get a black image

Comment: Flip faces is not the problem, lighting shouldn't be a problem as I'm not baking direct and indirect lighting, no intersecting objects... What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Since you have plugged in the *Mix* node directly into the *Material's output* slot which makes Blender use an *Emission* node internally, I would use the *Bake Type* `Emit` with 128 samples (or so). This bakes fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the same *Image Texture* in both the 2 materials of your object and keep them selected in order to bake these materials. Also you need to have a shader before the *Output* in your material called *concentric circles*. The length of the bake operation will next depend on the size of your *Image Texture* and on the *Render Max Samples*. It's pretty fast with a 1024 px image in my case (of course if it's 4096 it will be 16 times longer).

[image]

Result:

[image]